# How to apply C# LINQ to eliminate foreach loops?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

How to restructure these data-structures and data-processing code to use LINQ for brevity, clarity, and resource efficiency (cpu + memory ) ?

```
public class Account
{
    public string AccountNumber {get; set;}  
}

public class Customer
{
    public List<Account> Accounts {get; set;}  
}

public static void TransformAccount(Account account)
{
    if (account != null && account.AccountNumber != null)
    {
        account.AccountNumber = account.AccountNumber.Trim().TrimStart(new char[] {'0'});
    }
}

public static void TransformCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    if (customer == null || customer.Accounts == null) return;
    foreach (var account in customer.Accounts)
    {
        TransformAccount(account);
    }
}

public static ProcessCustomers(List<Customer> customers)
{
    if (customers != null)
    {
      foreach (var customer in customers)
      {
          TransformCustomer(customer);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: While using Linq can help with code readability and maintainability, it rarely makes code perform faster or more efficiently compared to an equivalent for/foreach/while loop.

Comment: And while LINQ is great for *querying* data, it's not intended to be used for *mutating* data as you're doing here. `foreach` loops are generally considered the proper way to do it. LINQ doesn't provide a `ForEach` extension method for that reason.

Comment: I don't see any improvements that can linq make, you might do something like: `customers .ForEach(x => { if x!= null) TransformCustomer(customer);});` but it's actually the same foreach only (I think) should be even slower.

Comment: _`and resource efficiency (cpu + memory )`_ - what exactly do you think LINQ does? [Here is the code for LINQ `.Where(...)`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L30-L36).

Comment: https://morelinq.github.io/2.8/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ForEach__1_1.htm

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is better for querying than it is for modifying data. That said, you could use LINQ to get the account items you wish to modify and make the changes in a foreach.

```
var customers = GetCustomers(); // Some method that gets a customer list

var toModify = from customer in customers where customer.Accounts != null
               from account in customer.Accounts where account.AccountNumber != null
               select account;

foreach(var item in toModify)
    item.AccountNumber = item.AccountNumber.Trim().TrimStart(new char[]{'0'});
```

This isn't necessarily going to be more performant than just using foreach loops, but you may find it more readable. So while you might get brevity and clarity, I don't think you're also going to get performance (as stated in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it in LINQ.

When using a dummy list of 1000 customers with 1000 accounts each, your code with foreach took 75 milliseconds and this LINQ took 123 milliseconds, almost twice the time.

```
    public static void ProcessCustomersLinq(List<Customer> customers)
    {
        customers?
            .Where(c => c != null && c.Accounts != null)
            .SelectMany(c => c.Accounts.Where(a => a != null))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(a => TrimAccountNumber(a));
    }

    private static void TrimAccountNumber(Account account)
    {
        account.AccountNumber = account.AccountNumber.Trim().TrimStart(new char[] { '0' });
    }
```

Comment: Consider using https://morelinq.github.io/2.8/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ForEach__1_1.htm to avoid the memory allocation cost of of the `ToList`.